# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

why do i get  ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ?

```
SQL> grant create view to rojib;
```

Error :

```
grant create view to rojib
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to grant the `CREATE VIEW` privilege, your user needs the `CREATE VIEW` privilege `WITH ADMIN OPTION`, or the `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE` system privilege. Otherwise you have insufficient privileges.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#i2094944

> To grant a system privilege, one of the following conditions must be
>   met:
>
> - You must have been granted the GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE system privilege.
>     In this case, if you grant the system privilege to a role, then a user
>     to whom the role has been granted does not have the privilege unless
>     the role is enabled in user's session.
> - You must have been granted the system privilege with the ADMIN OPTION.
>     In this case, if you grant the system privilege to a role, then a user
>     to whom the role has been granted has the privilege regardless whether
>     the role is enabled in the user's session.

Comment: Or the user must have the **DBA** role (which has amongst others the *GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE* role).